# Django import error in views - no module named 'x'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-urls

I keep getting an error that there's no such module.

The project name is gmblnew, and I have two subfolders- `core` and `gmblnew` - the app I'm working on is core.

My **urls.py** file is

```
from django.conf.urls import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'gmblnew.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^gmblnew/', include('gmblnew.foo.urls')),

    url(r'^league/', include('core.views.league')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

This seems to be fine. The **views.py** file is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def league(request):
    from core.models import Division
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['mimetype'] = 'text/plain'
    response.write("<HTML><>BODY>\n")
    response.write("< TABLE BORDER=1><CAPTION>League List</CAPTION><TR>\n")
    all_leagues = Division.objects.all()
    for league in all_leagues:
        response.write("<TR>\n")
        response.write("<TD> %s" % league)
        response.write("</TD>\n")
    response.write("</BODY></HTML>")
    return response
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/chris/Dropbox/Django/gmblnew/gmblnew/urls.py" in <module>
  12.   url(r'^league/', include('core.views.league')),
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  25.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /admin/
Exception Value: No module named league
```

I've tried a number of variants on the `url(r'^league/', include('core.views.league')),` line, including `gmblnew.core.views.league`, `views.league`, `views.view_league`, etc.  I'm obviously missing something super simple on the structure of that line.

Comment: Did you go through the tutorial? Your view method needs to be fixed.

Comment: That was sort of the point of the question.  Yes, I did, I was adapting it to what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
url(r'^league/', include('core.views.league')),
```

By using `include` you are specifying a module, which does not exist.

[`include` is used to include other url confs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs), and not to target view methods

What you want is refer to the view method `league`

```
url(r'^league/$', 'core.views.league'),
```

should work.

Also, note the `$` after `^league/` , which represents the *end* of the URL pattern.

Comment: Headdesk.  That worked.  Literally spent about 90 minutes trying to puzzle that out.  So simple.  :(  Incidentally, the output test HTML was gibberish, but I've sorted that too.  Aaaarrrrgh.  Thanks.

Comment: I understand. Spending hours together on trivial things is not new to me.. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

`include` takes a path to a url file, not a view. Just write this instead:

```
url(r'^league/', 'core.views.league'),
```